# In service oriented architecture, Is it a good practise that a mapper calls a service?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, clean-architecture

I would like to know whether it is a good practise to call/inject a (micro) service inside a custom object mapper.

This mapper transform an Entity to a DTO. In this DTO there is a field that contains a sum up of some values (need some business logic). I defined a service to centralice the logic as it is used in many other places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there is strictly speaking nothing incorrect about calling a service from a mapper, it does add dependencies to the mapper, which is usually a pure object (Plain Old Java Object, POJO) that simply converts an object of one type to another. An alternative is to pass the required information into the mapper as a parameter. For example, suppose your current design resembles the following:

```
public class Foo { /* ... */}
public class FooDto { /* ... */}

public class FooService {

    public FooResults getSomeResults() { /* ... */ }
}

public class FooMapper {

    private final FooService service;

    public FooMapper(FooService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public FooDto convert(Foo foo) { 

        FooResults results = service.getSomeResults();

        // ... use results ...
    }
}
```

Instead of having the `FooMapper` dependent on the `FooService`, you can pass the `FooResults` in as a parameter to the `convert` method:

```
public class FooMapper {

    public FooDto convert(Foo foo, FooResults results) {    
        // ... use results ...
    }
}
```

The advantage to this approach is that `FooMapper` is no longer dependent on `FooService`. Instead, the client that calls the `convert` method must have a reference to the `FooService` to obtain a `FooResults` object.

Comment: I like this approach. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

A mapper converts one datastructure to another datastructure. Thus it should only depend one these two data structures.

```
 +------------------+              +----------+           +------------------+   
 | data structure 1 |   <-----     |  mapper  |  ----->   | data structure 2 | 
 +------------------+              +----------+           +------------------+
```

If a mapper uses a service it also depends on that service. This means that it knows how the data is obtained. I guess your mapper depends on a concrete service. So the mapper will be affected of changes to one of the data structures and changes to that service.

```
 +------------------+              +----------+           +------------------+   
 | data structure 1 |   <-----     |  mapper  |  ----->   | data structure 2 | 
 +------------------+              +----------+           +------------------+  
                                        |
                                        V
                                   +----------+    
                                   |  service | 
                                   +----------+
```

It might be hard to mock the service for testing. Maybe the service depends on some kind of repositories or it does SQL itself.

It might be better to make the mapper independent of the source of the data structure by introducing an interface that abstracts from the way the data is obtained. Your service can then implement that interface or create a simple adapter.

```
 +------------------+              +----------+           +------------------+   
 | data structure 1 |   <-----     |  mapper  |  ----->   | data structure 2 | 
 +------------------+              +----------+           +------------------+  
                                        |
                                        V
                               +------------------+          +--------------+
                               |   Data1Provider  | <------  |   service    |
                               +------------------+          +--------------+
```

With this approach you inverse the dependency to the service by introducing a stable abstraction of how to get the data. That's called dependency inversion.

It might be a simple interface that looks like this

```
 public interface Data1Provider {
      public FooResults getResults();
 }
```

This interface can be easily mocked for tests.

Another good approach is to simply call the service before you call the mapper. Just pass the data that the service returned to the mapper. I will not go into the details here, because [Justin Albano's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57011714/974186) answer already shows it.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answers!
The service is a Spring Service and it is injected into the mapper with `@Autowired` (the mapper has `@Component` annotation). I consider this structure as DI as well, right?   

Anyways, I went into Justin Albano's solution! :)

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned that Jusin Albano's approach is a good solution. So if youre fine with this, do it. You should keep in mind that dependency inversion is not the same as dependency injection. Unfortunately they doth have the same abbreviation DI. Dependency inversion is about turning compile time dependencies to runtime dependencies. The source code dependency points against the flow of control. Take a look at the mapper above, the flow of control is mapper -> service, but the source code dependency is mapper -> Data1Provider <- service.